# AWS Elastic Beanstalk on Single Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-application-load-balancer

Does anyone know a **current** way to get Elastic Beanstalk working on a single instance via the AWS console?

I have gone through multiple tutorials but none seem to have worked.

The cost of leveraging a Load Balancer is too high. It runs more than 3x the cost of my EC2 instance. Hence I'm on the quest to run on a single instance and eliminate the need to use a Load Balancer.

I've done multiple tutorials and all of them resulted in my web app not being accessible over HTTPS or HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the presets are single instance. I just launched a "hello world" application and it works. Can you provide more details of your problem.
[image]

[image]